# Dictionary in .net core

Tags: generics

Can someone please tell me what does the Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryAdd(TKey, TValue) method do?

The documentation is weak, to say the least.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=netcore-2.0#Definition

I tried looking for the source:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic

But I can't find the source for the Dictionary class.

Answer (score 1):

A Dictionary stores `values` based on a **unique** `key`.  The values could be anything but the key has to be unique.  This makes it very fast to find the `value` if you know they `key`.

You can think of it as a real dictionary.  You don't know the definition of the word but the definition is easy to find once you look up the word (alphabetically).

Another example is a description of the house where the address is the key.  It is hard and slow to search for a particular house but if you know the address, it is easy and fast.

When you declare a Dictionary, you specify what type the key and the value will be.  When using Generics, this is done at runtime instead of when you write the code.

For `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryAdd(TKey, TValue)`, the idea is to first check to see if the `key` is already present and only add the `value` if the `key` is not there.  If the `key` is already in the dictionary, the `value` will **not** be added (just like you can't have the same word twice in the dictionary or the same address twice in the same city).  What more, the function returns a **Boolean** that tells you if the the value was added or not.  This way you don't have to handle an error (exception) if the value did not add to the Dictionary.

Here are some links that can help with the .NET specifics

- https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/dictionary-in-C-Sharp/
- https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/how-to-create-and-use-dictionary-csharp/
- https://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/c-generic-dictionary-tutorial-with-example.php